# Pass parameters from main report to sub reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, subreport

I have searched many sites for this but the suggestions do not work. I set 2 parameters on the main report. I have added the 2 sub reports, both are to use the same values of these parameters. The 2 parameters are date values I need to use as a date range in the select expert where I am using a `Is Between` check. I right click on the sub report and click the `Change the sub report links`. When I select the parameter in the `Available Fields:` drop down the `Select data in subreport based on field:` is not populated with any choices - which was one of the suggestions I read about. Can someone walk me thru this process?

Thanks

Comment: You have to create parameters in Sub reports first for them to appear in the list and then  map to main reports parameters

Comment: Right you are about connecting them! I am out of time to test it, be back tomorrow. Write it up as answer. @aMazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create parameters in your Sub reports first for them to appear in the Connecting list and then map to main reports parameters

Comment: This does work, but the thing I noticed was it now takes the report a very long time and I can see it going thru a couple million records. Why would this slow it down so much?

Comment: You will probably need to filter down your results in your main report, such that less records are passed down to the subreports. Probably change your sql query.

Comment: This report prior to adding these parameters ran in under a second. There shouldn't be any records being passed to the sub reports as they are very different in what tables they connect to. Thanks

Comment: Well, the sub report before didnt have anything to show which is why it was quick. But anyway you can filter the records in the sub-report. If possible note which records are being passed, you will then be able to figure out what could be the problem

Comment: The sub reports had those values set differently - in the select expert, and there was data. Now I am moving to parameters. Same queries for each report. I don't understand what you mean by the records get passed down to the sub reports - they are reports from diff tables??? They just need the date values that are passed down from the main report.